# Intellij marks all methods as unused even though they are used

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is part of the code.

```
public class MyPolynomial {

    private double coeffs[];
    private int degree;

    public MyPolynomial(double ... coeffs) {
        if (coeffs != null && coeffs.length > 0) {
            this.coeffs = new double[coeffs.length];
            System.arraycopy(coeffs, 0, this.coeffs, 0, coeffs.length);
        }
    //this.coeffs = Arrays.copyOf(coeffs, coeffs.length);
    }

    public MyPolynomial(String filename) {
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.degree = in.nextInt();
        coeffs = new double[degree+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < coeffs.length; i++) {
            coeffs[i] = in.nextDouble();
        }

    }

    public String getCoeffs() {
        return Arrays.toString(coeffs);
    }

}
```

The class, the constructors, as well as all the methods are marked as unused.
But I did use them in the test file. It compiles and runs as expected.

Part of the test file:

```
MyPolynomial aTest = new MyPolynomial(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    System.out.println(aTest.getCoeffs());
    System.out.println(aTest.getDegree());
    System.out.println(aTest);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can check with your IDE vendor, this seems no programming problem.

Comment: Not sure that testfiles counts as "being used", since the code is not used in the real application

Comment: I created a simple project with your `MyPolynomial` class and then a `MyPolynomailTest` class and it all works fine for me. `MyPolynomial` class is marked as being used and also the methods in the class. Try to invalidate caches from the `File` menu.

Comment: Invalidating caches did it. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to mark 'public' method as unused.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by invalidating caches in the File menu.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue. If you elaborate on how you solved you problem (in your answer), you are far more likely to get upvotes!

Comment: Press Shift twice. It will open a dialogue box that searches everywhere in Intellij. Search with word "caches" and it will give an option to "Invalidate Caches and Restart". Read the warning before accepting and select it. It will restart Intellij and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what Serge Baranov describes here really helped me:
[IDE incorrectly showing classes and methods as unused](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000110290-IDE-incorrectly-showing-classes-and-methods-as-unused)
Just make sure to select this options in the Invalidate Caches:
[Invalidate Caches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHj5D.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).